# Saturation of vector mean

Tags: r, mean

I have a vector and would like to see a saturation of the mean.
The mean calculation is extended to stepwise the next element of vector.

Actual I have a running version, but due to the fact that I have more than 100000 elements this runs much too long.
Is there any idea to speed this up ?

```
 # create sample vector    
set.seed(12345)
iterations <- 10000   
t <- runif(iterations, min = 0, max = 10)

results <- NULL
for(i in 1:iterations ) 
{
    results[i] <- mean(t[1:i])   # calculate the mean for the first i elements
}
plot(results)
```

Comment: I guess this is correct `plot(cumsum(t) / seq_along(t))`. Something like a "cumulative mean"?

Comment: Thanks alexis, gives the same result, but about factor 10 faster

Comment: Good answer, now I know about seq_along.